# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout

Tags: android-support-library, android-snackbar

I'm m using snackbar first time but this error comes during running my application.

Error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout
```

Code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view;
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openContextMenu(v);
        String s = "Task Done";
        ====>>>Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();<====error shown in this line
    }
});
```

gradle.build

```
dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Hi Sanket. Could you please update your question with full logcat error?

Comment: thank you for asking....now problem is solved...i have updated my dependencies.